# dragging same element li of div second time should not be drag and drop

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

When dragging and dropping an element from `<div id="catalog" >` to a box i.e `<div id="dialogIteration">` works fine .But when the same element is dragged and dropped for the second time , its easily get dropped But What i want that It should not be dropped and  give alert that "Statement already exits" .

Example code http://jsfiddle.net/coolanuj/7683X/28

Answer (score 2):

Use a flag inside your `draggable` which would indicate whether it has already been dropped inside your dialog.

```
drop: function (evt, ui) {
    // logic
    if (ui.draggable.attr('data-dropped')) {
        // don't perform the drop
    } else {
        // perform the drop
        ui.draggable.attr('data-dropped', true);
    }
}
```

If you want only the one that is currently being dropped to not be `droppable` anymore then reset the `draggable` attribute upon successful drop.

```
drop: function (evt, ui) {
    // logic
    if (ui.draggable.attr('data-dropped')) {
        // don't perform the drop
    } else {
        // perform the drop
        $('tag[data-dropped=true]').attr('data-dropped', false);
        ui.draggable.attr('data-dropped', true);
    }
}
```

Comment: D-Infragistics : Thanx for your valuable answer . Code is working and even i'm getting alert that i have added to this code . But what my requirement is that  if i start drag the same element for the second time then there only i should get an alert - "This element has already been dragged"

Comment: Then perform the check inside the drag method. Cancel the drag event and alert.

Comment: D-Infragistics : Thanx for ur answer . I have one more issue . I have posted one question here but still no one has answered it can you help me out . link is here



stackoverflow.com/questions/13264318/dragging-and-dropping-one-dialog-box-into-another-box-adding-unnecessarily-scrol#comment18109544_13264318

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example : http://jsfiddle.net/7683X/35/

I used `:contains` selector to check if the text has already been dropped into the droppable element :

```
drop: function(event, ui) {
    if($("#dialogIteration ol:contains('"+ui.draggable.text()+"')").length > 0)
    {
       alert("Statement already exits");
       return false;
    }

    ...
}
```